# script or command to change the starting index number of a set of sequentially numbered files

Tags: linux, shell, file-rename

i have a set of files named img1.png , img2.png ,...img10.png,.. and so on. what i want to achieve is renaming these files so that the starting index is increased by 30 such that the files become img31.png, img32.png,.....img40.png,....and so on. Is this possible using the "rename" command? or is a script required? in either case how do i do this?

related - for this to work do i have to first rename the files to img001.png, img002.png, ...img010.png , and so on?  how is this to be done, if required?

Answer (score 2):

add 30 to the numbers in each filename

```
rename 's/(\d+)/$1+30/e' *png
```

rename to be 3 digits long

```
rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf("%03d",$1)/e' *png
```

See perldoc perlre http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html  for details of how this works, rename is a perl program

Comment: For renaming Git patch files (appending them to an existing list of 25), I used `rename 's/(\d+)-/sprintf("%04d",$1+25)/e' *.patch`

Answer (score -1):

```
LOCATION=/my/image/directory #change this to your location
for file in $(ls -1 ${LOCATION})
do
  ind=$(echo ${file}|cut -c 4-|cut -d"." -f1)
  (( newind=${ind}+30 ))
  mv ${LOCATION}/${file} ${LOCATION}/img${newind}.png
done
```

I am sure there is much more elegant way of doing this on one line using likes of awk/sed/perl etc, but this shows you the logic behind it.

Hope it helps

Comment: 1) [don't iterate over $(ls)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `for file in "$LOCATION/*`. 2) You also need to quote `"$file"` everywhere. Both of these are to protect you from files with whitespace in the name.

Comment: I beg to differ. Your statements are making assumptions. Mine are generic for *ANY* Unix flavor.

Comment: I make no assumptions in my last comment